# A set of zero harmonic measure 2

Tags: real-analysis, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Let  be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, $m\geq 2$, and  the interior of the closure of . Let  be a subset of ∂∩ (∂ means boundary) such that:

1) $E$ has positive ($m-$dimensional) Lebesgue measure

2) $E$ has no bounded component in $W$.

Can (,V)()=0  ((,V) is the harmonic measure of V at ∈V)?

Comment: Set $V$ to be the union of balls $B_j$ such that the closures of $B_j$ are pairwise disjoint, $V$ dense in $B(0,1)$, and $B(0,1) \setminus V$ has positive Lebesgue measure. Then set $E = B(0,1) \setminus \bigcup_j \overline{B}_j$.

Comment: Yes, it can, as I explained in my answer to your previous question of the same title. For example when $m=2$ a simple curve in the plane can have positive Lebesgue measure. Instead of the segment $[0,1]$ in my previous example, use this curve.